# How can I set webFrame in electron rendeerer process? - Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

This is my main.js, from this file I generate an exe file that I need for my purpose. Here is the thing, I need to add a protection against pinch zooming, in documentation it says you can do this by adding [Webframe](https://xwartz.gitbooks.io/electron-gitbook/content/en/api/web-frame.html) component to reender but I cant seem to manage to find where is reenderer. My application is basicaly main.js and index.html that main reads, I tried to put it into script tag in index.html but no succes. please help

```
const electron = require('electron')
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')


// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window 
will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
// Create the browser window.
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1820, height: 1080, transparent:true, 
resizable:false, autoHideMenuBar:true, frame:false })
mainWindow.setFullScreen(true);
// and load the index.html of the app.
mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
protocol: 'file:',
slashes: true

}))

//Accessing the Dev tools
//mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
// mainWindow.webContents.on('devtools-opened', () => {
//   setImmediate(() => {
    // do whatever you want to do after dev tool completely opened here
 //      mainWindow.focus();
//  });
//})

// Open the DevTools.
 mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

 // Emitted when the window is closed.
 mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
 // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
 // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
 // when you should delete the corresponding element.
 mainWindow = null
 })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  const {webFrame} = require('electron')

  webFrame.setZoomLevelLimits(1,1);
  webFrame.
  console.log(webFrame)
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same confusion. The renderer process is the code that runs your site/app, so your index.html file or any other application js files. I was able to place the following into index.html and get the results I was looking for.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const webFrame = require('electron').webFrame;
        webFrame.setZoomFactor(1);
        webFrame.setZoomLevelLimits(1, 1);
        webFrame.setVisualZoomLevelLimits(1, 1);
        webFrame.setLayoutZoomLevelLimits(0, 0);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded in getting it to work with [angular-electron](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron).

Specifically, in the [electron-service.ts](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron/blob/master/src/app/providers/electron.service.ts) I added:

```
import { webFrame } from 'electron';
...
webFrame: typeof webFrame;
...
constructor() {
  if(this.Electron()) {
  ...
  this.webFrame = window.require('electron').webFrame;
...
}
```

Finally, anywhere in your component, once the *ElectronService* is injected, you can use it:

```
this.electronService.webFrame.setZoomFactor(0.8);
```